# Build datetime in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to build a `datetime` in a select statement based on another 2 columns (`datetime`).

I cannot seem to get the conversion correct. Can you spot what I am doing wrong?
It seems to me that `DatePart` it omits the "0" part of the day

Below script should create all the data necessary

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name='TestDB')
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE TestDB 
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

    DROP DATABASE TestDB
END

CREATE DATABASE TestDB
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestTable]','U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateSample1] datetime NOT NULL,
    [DateSample2] datetime NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT dbo.TestTable (DateSample1, DateSample2)
VALUES('2006-10-06 00:00:00.000', '2007-01-17 00:00:00.000')

/*
In your select statement you should return another column "DateSample3"
and this should be year from DateSample1 and month and day from dateSample2
*/
--my try1
SELECT 
    tt.DateSample1, tt.DateSample2,
    DateSample3 = CAST(DATEPART(YYYY, tt.DateSample1) AS CHAR(4)) 
            + CAST(DATEPART(MM, tt.DateSample2) AS CHAR(2)) 
            + CAST(DATEPART(dd, tt.DateSample2) AS CHAR(2))
        ,WantedResultForDateSample3='2006-01-17 00:00:00.000'
FROM 
    dbo.TestTable tt

--mytry2 THROWS AN ERROR
--Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
/*
SELECT 
    tt.DateSample1, tt.DateSample2,
    DateSample3 = CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST(DATEPART(YYYY, tt.DateSample1) AS CHAR(4)) 
            + CAST(DATEPART(MM, tt.DateSample2) AS CHAR(2)) 
            + CAST(DATEPART(dd, tt.DateSample2) AS CHAR(2)),120),
    WantedResult='2006-01-17 00:00:00.000'
FROM 
    dbo.TestTable tt
*/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx)

```
DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(tt.DateSample1),
                  MONTH(tt.DateSample2),
                  DAY(tt.DateSample2),
                  0,0,0,0)
```

Which is a lot cleaner than constructing a string IMO.

Whichever method you use you might have to deal with impossible dates with this requirement. One approach is below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN month=2 
             AND day = 29 
             AND (yr % 4 != 0 OR (yr % 100 = 0 AND yr % 400 != 0))
            THEN NULL
            ELSE
            DATETIMEFROMPARTS(yr,
                              month,
                              day,
                              0,0,0,0)
             END
 FROM [dbo].[TestTable] tt
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (YEAR(tt.DateSample1),
                     MONTH(tt.DateSample2),
                       DAY(tt.DateSample2))) V(yr, month, day)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c952/1)

Comment: WOW,that is it i didnt know about datetimefromparts existed

Comment: @developer9969 - There is always the possibility with this requirement that it won't be possible though and will fail. i.e. trying to transplant 29 Feb from a leap year to a non leap year.

Comment: you know what I have exactly that problem. how do i quickly find out all dates that fall into that .do you do where datepart(mm,datesample2)=2 and datepart(dd,datesample2)=29